# Como deixar o "bind" to "SQLiteStatement" aceitar uma valor null no SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

Resolvi usar o SQLiteStatement por ser mais rápido para inserir dados no SQLite, porém em algum momento pode vir um valor nulo objeto.getAlgumacoisa() e neste caso da um erro com a mensagem que o bind está vazio. Alguém sabe como resolver isso? no banco já criei autorizei valor null na tabela.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO table (number, nick) VALUES (?, ?)";
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    stmt.bindString(1, values.get(i).number);
    stmt.bindString(2, values.get(i).nick);
    stmt.execute();
    stmt.clearBindings();
}
```

*No sql, basta não colocar o "not null" na hora de criar as tabelas que a tabela aceita, mas com o bind está dando erro antes de tentar inserir na tabela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem duas formas mas ambas necessitam um teste prévio que verifique se o valor é nulo:

- Usando [bindNull()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteProgram.html#bindNull%28int%29)

  ```
  String sql = "INSERT INTO table (number, nick) VALUES (?, ?)";
  SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
  for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
      if(values.get(i).number == null){
          stmt.bindNull(1);
      }else{
          stmt.bindString(1, values.get(i).number);
      }
      if(values.get(i).nick == null){
          stmt.bindNull(2);
      }else{
          stmt.bindString(2, values.get(i).nick);
      }
      stmt.execute();
      stmt.clearBindings();
  }
  ```
- Não fazer *bind* para esse *index*, desde que antes tenha feito `clearBindings()`

  ```
  String sql = "INSERT INTO table (number, nick) VALUES (?, ?)";
  SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
  for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
      if(values.get(i).number != null){
          stmt.bindString(1, values.get(i).number);
      }
      if(values.get(i).nick != null){
          stmt.bindString(2, values.get(i).nick);
      }
      stmt.execute();
      stmt.clearBindings();
  }
  ```

Comment: é, eu queria evitar de fazer essa verificação mas vou ter que usar isso mesmo. obrigadão.